# What is the GPU driver I am currently running?

Tags: ubuntu, drivers, nvidia, gpu

I have installed latest nVidia graphic driver via this PPA "xorg-edgers/ppa". Now in Nvidia X server setting showing the driver version is 346.35. But in Ubuntu's Additional Drivers there is no such driver rather it marks the Nouveau driver.

I ran `lspci -vnn | grep -i VGA -A 12`.

```
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: NVIDIA Corporation GF104 [GeForce GTX 460] [10de:0e22] (rev a1) (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])
Subsystem: Gigabyte Technology Co., Ltd Device [1458:34fc]
Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 53
Memory at fc000000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=32M]
Memory at d8000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=128M]
Memory at d4000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=64M]
I/O ports at b800 [size=128]
[virtual] Expansion ROM at fe780000 [disabled] [size=512K]
Capabilities: <access denied>
Kernel driver in use: nvidia

01:00.1 Audio device [0403]: NVIDIA Corporation GF104 High Definition Audio     Controller [10de:0beb] (rev a1)
Subsystem: Gigabyte Technology Co., Ltd Device [1458:34fc]
```

Which version of graphic driver I am using currently ? If I am not using nVidia's driver then how can I use nVidia's driver. I am running Ubuntu 14.04 64bit OS.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**Update** typing:

```
nvidia-smi
```

gives you the driver verson nowadays.

**Old answer:**

Typing `nvidia-settings --version` will tell you what version of the NVidia driver is currently installed (even when it's not running).

`lsmod | grep video` will show you the running video module.

`modinfo szWhateverWasTheOutputOfThePreviousCommand` will give you the version of the *running* module.

Comment: thanks for the reply. but `lsmod | grep video` does not show anything. @Fabby

Comment: Try copy-pasting the command because unless you're running a server that has no GUI, it should output *something* (actually a few lines).  BTW, the xorg.edgers is an "open-source" x server repackaging of the NVidia proprietary drivers, so it shows up like "nouveau" under the GUI anyway...  so you should be fine in all cases (just double-verified)

Comment: The linux kernel has *modules*, but Xorg has *drivers*.

Comment: Updated.  Not as funny as before now however, but indeed more correct. @fwyzard

Answer (score 0):

If using prime-select (nVidia Optimus) on Ubuntu 18.04 (Dell XPS 15 9570) then use:

`prime-select query`

and it responds with intel or nvidia, depending on what you chose last.